# WCF exception handling error

Tags: wcf, exception

Please guide what is exact problem
my `GlobalErrorHandlerBehavoiurAttribute` class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;`enter code here`
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
namespace HelloService

{
  public class GlobalErrorHandlerBehavoiurAttribute:Attribute,IServiceBehavior
    {
      private readonly Type errorhanderType;
      public GlobalErrorHandlerBehavoiurAttribute(Type errorhanderType)
      {
          this.errorhanderType = errorhanderType;
      }
        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, 

System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, 
System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, 
System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {

        }
        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
        {
            IErrorHandler handler = (IErrorHandler)Activator.CreateInstance(this.errorhanderType);
            foreach (ChannelDispatcherBase ChannelDispatcherBase in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
            {
                ChannelDispatcher channeldispatcher = ChannelDispatcherBase as ChannelDispatcher;
                if (channeldispatcher != null)
                {
                    channeldispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Add(handler);
                }                                         
            }
        }

        public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

my GlobalErrorHandler class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
namespace HelloService
{
   public class GlobalErrorHandler:IErrorHandler
    {
        public bool HandleError(Exception error)
        {
            return true;
        }                                                                      

        public void ProvideFault(Exception error, System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageVersion version, ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message fault)
        {
            if (error is FaultException)
                return;
            FaultException faultexception = new FaultException("A General Error has occured");
            MessageFault messagefault = faultexception.CreateMessageFault();
            fault = Message.CreateMessage(version,messagefault,null);
        }
    }
}
```

my service implementation code

```
public int Divide(int num,int dem)
    {
        //if (dem == 0)
        //{
        //    throw new FaultException("Dem can not be zero", new FaultCode("DivideByZero"));
        //}
        //try
        //{
            return num / dem;

    enter code here
        //}
        //catch (DivideByZeroException ex)
        //{
        //    DivideByZeroFault dividebyzero = new DivideByZeroFault();
        //    dividebyzero.Error = ex.Message;
        //    dividebyzero.Details = "Deno can not be greater than zero";
        //    throw new FaultException<DivideByZeroFault>(dividebyzero);
        //}
    }
```

my application button click

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //CompanyService.CompanyPublicServiceClient client = new CompanyService.CompanyPublicServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_ICompanyPublicService");
            int num = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
            int dem = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
            //HelloService.IHelloService client = new HelloService.HelloServiceClient("wsHttpBinding_IHelloService");
           // HelloService.IHelloService client = new HelloService.HelloServiceClient();
            label2.Text = client.Divide(num, dem).ToString();
        }
        catch (FaultException faultexecption)
        {
            label2.Text =  faultexecption.Message;
        }
```

When we pass 10/0 it will dispaly "A General Error has occured" message of `GlobalErrorHandler` class. but it is not displaying. I have put braekpoints in `GlobalErrorHandler` class but it is not going in `GlobalErrorHandler`  class.

Comment: Turn on break on exception thrown. Turn off "just my code".

Comment: little bit confusing. please tell me what to do exactly.

Comment: Menu->Debug->Exceptions... Check the box to break on exception thrown.
Menu->Tools->Options... On LHS choose "Debugging" Find "Enable Just My Code" on the RHS and un-check it.

Comment: I have Turn on exception thrown also of service and application also.But problem is still persist.

Comment: Of course it still persists! But now you can see the point it is thrown.

Comment: No sir If we tick "Enable Just My Code" off then we we are unable to access my service. and when we tick it then we can access service but problem not resolved.

Comment: **why** are you unable to access the service? **what happens**????

Comment: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. while untick "Enable Just My Code"  and run application

Comment: OK Great! This means that there was an exception on the SERVER. Usually, some information on the type of exception will be passed in the HTTP response body, and this will be packaged into the exception.So, while stopped on breakpoint examine the exception properties. Maybe there is information in there which is useful.